# BigQuery's hive partitioned table performance

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to take advantage of the hive partitioned table. I have encountered the problem that retrieving Parquet files directly from GCS is several times faster than retrieving the same data using the hive partitioned external table.

My data is stored in parquet format in the following structure:

```
gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/m=0/000
gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/m=0/001
gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/m=0/...
```

"h" stands for an hour, and "m" stands for a minute. "mybucket" is on region "us-central1".

Querying parquet files directly takes 3 seconds:

```
bq --project_id=chronosphere-production --location us-central1 query --nouse_cache --use_legacy_sql=false --external_table_definition='trace::PARQUET=gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/*' "SELECT name, count(*) as c FROM people GROUP BY name ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 20"
```

The other query, which runs on the same data but using hive partitioned table where hive url is `gs://mybucket/dataset/{dt:DATE}/{h:INTEGER}/{m:INTEGER}` takes 12 seconds:

```
bq --location us-central1 query --nouse_cache --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT name, count(*) as c FROM \`dataset.hive_table\` WHERE dt='2019-06-17' AND h=5 GROUP BY name ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Both queries scan the same amount of data/rows, returns the same result. But the response time difference is huge. Any ideas what can be the reason for such a big difference?

BTW if I create a non-hive partitioned table that points to `gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5`, it performs as good as querying parquet files directly. I think it's ok as this is temporary table vs permanent table performance.

Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT:
It feels like it is related to file count, but I'm still not sure what is the root cause and if it's possible to solve it.
Here are some folder/file count numbers:

- dt=* folder count = 3
- h=* folder count per dt folder = 24
- m=* folder count per h folder = 60
- files per m folder ~40

My query scans ~32M rows / 500Mb of data.

I assume that when I provide a filter like `WHERE dt='2019-06-17' AND h=5`, BigQuery should go directly to `gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/` and start searching for files from there, but it feels that's not what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a significant number of files in the bucket, as this is largely a comparison of cloud storage object listing performance.  It's not clear from the description how many objects are involved, and how they're distributed across your partitioning scheme.  Is that a typical date, or an unusual one in terms of data distribution?

In the hive partitioned case, BigQuery must get the larger list of bucket objects (e.g. `gs://mybucket/dataset/*`) and *then* filter it, whereas in the non-hive cases you describe you're effectively pushing a more targeted filter to cloud storages's list operations (e.g. `gs://mybucket/dataset/dt=2019-06-17/h=5/*`).

The calculus here is whether the performance implications outweigh other factors like convenience/manageability/etc.  There's likely a middle ground to consider as well, which would be to experiment using more of the dt prefix for defining yearly/monthly tables to see if you get a more satisfactory performance tradeoff.

Comment: I have added numbers about file count to my initial question.

Comment: Per your edit, the filecount is an order of magnitude less than what I was expecting.  Only other thing I can think of confirming would be the storage bucket location/storageclass.

Comment: Both bucket and query run on `us-central1`. I think this issue is related to hive partitioning, because as I mention if I create a non-hive partitioned table then it performs well. Also, when comparing execution plans, the read time of the hive partitioned table and the non-hive partitioned table is the same, just for the hive partitioned table there is a huge time gap after starting the query. Literally, it "sleeps" for 10 seconds and then reads data. I see a gap with a non-hive partitioned table but "sleep" time is less than a second.

Comment: At this point I'd recommend reaching out to [support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support) if possible, as they'd have more diagnostic avenues to explore here.